# bash : $_ in cronjob is empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

```
cd some_dir && php some_crone.php || echo "$? $_" | xargs ./some_handler.php
```

So when I run this code from console I got a correct value for $? and for $_

$? - exit status 
$_  - Gives the last argument to the previous command. At the shell startup, it gives the absolute filename of the shell script being executed.

But when I put this code to cronjob :

```
crontab -e
*/1 * * * * cd some_dir && php some_crone.php || echo "$? $_" | xargs ./some_handler.php
```

I got an empty $_.
Please help. I can not understand what a problem?

Comment: Does cron use bash, or does it use sh?

Comment: cron uses sh, which can be a bash variant on most linuxes, but is dash on most recent variants of ubuntu

Comment: Well, there's your answer then.  $_ is a bash-ism, and it would do a person good to know not to use bash-isms in places where you're only guaranteed sh syntax.

Comment: Even if you do get Bash, it is invoked as `sh`, which disables many Bash features. The manual page explains which exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change crontab's default shell from /bin/sh to /bin/bash by adding the following line to your crontab.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```